# EditText not showing up when Activity holds multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

For the few people looking at my previous similar question, I deleted it and moved it here to be a more specific question now that I have a greater insight to the problem.

I have an Activity that holds one fragment on my standard phone, and holds two fragments on larger devices (tablets).  The Activity holds the options menu, as well as the EditText.  When I use my phone, everything loads fine.  When I use my tablet, the EditText is not shown in the Activity.  Here is the .xml files.

Activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xlmns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/trips_editText_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/searchClients"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:visibility="visible" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/trips_list"
        android:name="com.ib.dfm.TripsListFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:context=".TripsListActivity"
        android:layout="@layout/trip_list_item" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone figure out why the EditText will not show up on my tablet?  Also, if I try and access it programatically with `findViewById` I get null. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have multiple layouts defined for you activity?

Comment: @Niko Bingo.  This is a project I inherited from someone else and never became 100% familiar with the way they were working everything.  Feel free to post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have multiple layouts defined for your `Activity` and with tablet the xml file does not contain the `EditText`

Comment: Thanks very much, still have to wait 3 minutes and then I will accept this.

Answer (score 0):

You use fill_parent which has become deprecated, use match_parent instead. Hope it helps.

Comment: Not the exact solution to my problem, but definitely a good thing to note.  Thank you!